# How can I make the thread sleep for a while and then process all the messages?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm writing an Android app that uses two threads. One is UI thread and the other handles server communication. Is it possible for the other thread to wait for a specified amount of time and then process all the messages that have arrived and then wait again?

I need this so that I can collect different data and send it to server in one session.

I've build my thread with HandlerThread but now I'm stuck. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

This is the code I'm using inside the second thread:

```
public synchronized void waitUntilReady() {
        serverHandler = new Handler(getLooper()){

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  // msg queue
                switch(msg.what) {
                case TEST_MESSAGE:
                    testMessage(msg);
                    break;
                case UI_MESSAGE:
                    break;
                case SERVER_MESSAGE:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(msg.obj != null ? msg.obj.getClass().getName() : "is null");
                    break;
                 } 

            }


        };

}
```

**EDIT:**

I resolved my issue by going with Thread instead of HandlerThread and using queue.

I'm new to programming so I apologize for any horrenous errors but here's the code I ended up using.

```
public class ServiceThread extends Thread {

    // TODO maybe set the thread priority to background?
    static ServiceThread sThread = new ServiceThread();  // service thread instance
    private volatile Handler mainHandler;

    //
    public Thread mainThread;
    private boolean OK = true;
    public Queue<MessageService> msgQueue;
    private ThreadPoolExecutor exec;

    private ServiceThread() { }


    @Override
    public void run()  {
        synchronized (this){
            msgQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MessageService>();
            notifyAll();
        }

        mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        ThreadPoolExecutor exPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        exec = exPool;      

        // MAIN LOOP
            try {

                while(OK) {

                    getMessagesFromQueue();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //end of loop

    }

public void ProcessMessage(MessageService message) {
System.err.println("ProcessMessage with command: " + message.command);
}           
    /** Called from the Main thread. Waits until msgQueue is instantiated and then passes the reference
     * @return Message Queue
     */
    public Queue<MessageService> sendQueue() {
        synchronized (this){
            while(msgQueue == null) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  -- move the try block!
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return msgQueue;
    }

    public void setOkFalse () {
        if (OK == true)
            OK = false;
    }

    // Message handling methods



    /** Priority message from UI thread, processed in another thread ASAP.
     * Should be used on commands like getBigPicture or getPics when cached pics are running out
     * or upload picture etc.
     * @param message - Message should always be MessageService class
     * TODO check that it really is.
     */
    public void prioTask (MessageService message) {
        final MessageService taskMsg = message;
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){

                ProcessMessage(taskMsg);    
            }
        };
        exec.execute(task);
    }

    /**
     * Gets messages from queue, puts them in the list, saves the number of messages retrieved
     * and sends them to MessageService.handler(int commands, list messageList) 
     *  (method parameters may change and probably will =) ) 
     */
    public void getMessagesFromQueue() {
        int commands = 0;
        ArrayList <MessageService> msgList = new ArrayList <MessageService>(); 
        while(!msgQueue.isEmpty()) {
            if(msgQueue.peek() instanceof MessageService) {
                //put into list?
                msgList.add(msgQueue.remove());
                commands++;

            } else {
                //Wrong type of message
                msgQueue.remove();
                System.err.println("getMessagesFromQueue: Message not" +
                        " instanceof MessageService, this shouldn't happen!");
            }
        }       
        if (commands > 0) {
            HTTPConnection conn;
            try {
                conn = new HTTPConnection();
                    MessageService.handleSend(commands, msgList, conn);
                    conn.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

P.S. This is also my first post here. Should I mark it solved or something? How?

Comment: You will probably want to use a Timer/TimerTask rather than a literal sleep.  If your events need to wake up a sleeping device or restart the application when it has not been running, you may need to use the Alarm mechanism.

Comment: So I should just read the messages when they arrive then forward them to Timer that sends them to server at predetermined interval? Or is there a way to make the message queue wait with message processing using the timer? Last night I tried adding the sleep() after message processing but obviously then the message queue paused after each message and didn't process all the arrived messages at once.